# How to use Apple new color emoji font in Photoshop on Lion?

Tags: fonts, adobe-photoshop, osx-lion

There is a new *Apple Color Emoji* font in OS X Lion. However, the font text is not displayed properly in in Photoshop text layer (any Emoji character is transparent).

How can I make Photoshop display emoji properly. The emoji character looks good in TextEdit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Save the TextEdit document as PDF file.
Then open the PDF file in Photoshop and import only the picture you want.
Now you can use the emoji picutres.